# How to convert lists items from string to int?

Tags: python

I have a list of list of strings as the following list named `l`:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '2', '3', '4']]
```

I want to view the lists as int starting from item 2. The following code does the purpose but without converting the lists items to int:

```
>>> [l[i][2:] for i in range(len(l))]
[['3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '4']]
```

I tried `map()`, but the result was not successful as in:

```
>>> [map(int,l[i][2:]) for i in range(len(l))]
[<map object at 0x00000000029CAE10>, <map object at 0x00000000029CAF98>]
```

How can I convert my lists items from string to int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating over your primary list elements.

```
>>> A = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '2', '3', '4']]
>>> [list(map(int, x[2:])) for x in A]
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Calling `list()` forces Python 3 to fully evaluate the map - it's not necessary in Python 2.

Comment: But I want the result to be starting from position 2, therefore, I have to use [i][2:]. Can you clarify more based on my above explained example. I can not get what you want to say.

Comment: @user2192774 Yep, sorry I missed that initially.  I added that in afterward.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using `Python 3.x`. So `map` produces `map object` (which is an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map)). You can wrap it in `list` to see the results:

```
>>> l = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['2', '3', '2', '3', '4']]
>>> [list(map(int,l[i][2:])) for i in range(len(l))]
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Second, you iterate index `i` over `range` and then use random-access over initial list. In Python you can just iterate over the list without indices: `[list(map(int,sub_list[2:])) for sub_list in l]`

But I think it's more Pythonic to use list comprehensions:

```
>>> [[int(i) for i in sub_list[2:]] for sub_list in l]
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4]]
```